# Selenium grid 2 internet explorer is really slow

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I have been trying out Selenium Grid 2 and I have noticed that Internet Explorer is really slow with Grid 2 (no problem with Chrome or Firefox).  I know that in general Internet Explorer is slow with Selenium but with Grid 2, there are significant delay between each key being sent to the text box like 4,5 seconds delay. I'm not sure if it is because of the configuration.  Here are how I start a node with 1 instance of IE:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5553 -nodeTimeout 120 -maxSessions 1 -browser browserName=iexplore,maxInstances=1 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\grid2\drivers\IEDriverServer.exe
```

I'm currently testing grid2 with IWebDriver and C#

Comment: What version of IE? Is it a 64-bit or 32-bit version of IE?

Comment: I had similar issues, have you explored use of CSS Selectors and XPath as all these browsers have different performance issues on how you are finding these elements.

Comment: I'm currently using IEDriverServer 64-bit

Comment: @PatrickMagee : The problem that I'm having is if I'm going to send the input characters to a textbox then I'm having 4,5 seconds delay between each character being sent. Our existing test suite is implemented with XPath and I'm considering trying out CSS Locator since I heard it's faster with IE

Comment: What OS is this on? Have you tried the 32-bit version?

Comment: @Arran : This is on Windows 7 64-bit and I have tried both version 64-bit and 32-bit of IEDriverServer and I'm having issue for both version

Answer (score 1):

I've not noticed a slowness with IE9 personally, via a Grid.  I run the Grid and Hub separately though.

If per-character typing into fields is too slow, then you can just "set the value" on the text field so you don't need to wait for each key to type.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and solved it by updating the IEDriverServer to version 2.41.

Side-note: The actual release that fixed it for us is [IEDriverServer_Win32_2.41.0.zip](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.41.0.zip) even though this Grid node is 64-bit. The developer who maintains this setup said the 64-bit driver version 2.41.0 still exhibited the same behaviour.

Background: It has to be something on the Selenium Grid node and nothing to do with the client. The delay for typing text into input files is added on the Selenium Grid node.  The client only sends a JSON object in a POST request that sets the value of a DOM element, where the value is specified as an array.

```
    client$ sudo ngrep '' port 4444
    ...
    T client:40484 -> hub:4444 [AP]
      POST /wd/hub/session/0002d13c-c33e-4352-89be-eb6c0bfe16b7/element/6/value HTTP/1.1..Host: hub:4444..Accept-Encoding: identity..Conte
      nt-Length: 195..Connection: keep-alive..Content-type: application/json;charset="UTF-8"..POST: /wd/hub/session/0002d13c-c33e-4352-89be-eb6c0b
      fe16b7/element/6/value..Accept: application/json..User-Agent: Python http auth....
    T client:40484 -> hub:4444 [AP]
      {"sessionId": "0002d13c-c33e-4352-89be-eb6c0bfe16b7", "id": "6", "value": ["S", "a", "n", " ", "D", "o", "n", "a", "t", "o", " ", "M", "i", 
      "l", "a", "n", "e", "s", "e", " ", "(", "M", "I", ")"]}
```